# Druapl show unserialize() error after restore database

Tags: postgresql, drupal

The Drupal version is 7.34

Database is PostgreSQL 9.3.3

PHP is 5.4.39

Testing restore database at shared web hosting (restore the whole database after delete it)

No error if I just restore the records (empty all the tables records)

Show below error after restore database

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 13 bytes in variable_initialize() (line 936 of /home/www/mywebsite.me/includes/bootstrap.inc).

There're more error like the above line, I just skip them for brevity.
These error all related to the table with a field that has bytea type.

I also have a development environment built up by myself. No such error occur. Although the PostgreSQL and PHP version is different to what the shared web hosting provided to me.
Development environment PostgreSQL is 9.3.5

Comment: X-posted to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/153894/19635

Comment: I strongly suspect that the setting `bytea_output` is different between your two databases, so Drupal (which uses the PHP driver for PostgreSQL) is mangling binary data. Check `SELECT version(), current_setting('bytea_output')` on both servers please, and post results here

Comment: The setting of bytea_output in my development server was comment out (has a # at the start of the line). Dont know how the webhosting company set this value. Is changing this value to "escape" work ?